# Webservice returning text/plain whern text/xml is expected?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, peoplesoft

I need to use People Soft's component interface in order to communicate with People Soft. I can't find any sort of documentation for this so I'm having to go off an old version of software in house that interfaces with an old version of People Soft to learn it.

The People Soft people I work with also don't know anything about the Component Interface, but but they have evidently set up some web services with and given me the wsdl files.  I've got it set up in VS2k8 and wrote a little application to try calling a webservice to see if it works.  I get this message:

> Client found response content type of
>   'text/plain; charset=UTF-8', but
>   expected 'text/xml'.

Googling it hasn't given me much help. I asked the PS guys to look through the settings and see if there is a way to change the output, but they say they don't see anything like that in there.

The address I got from the WSDL for the webservice is http:///PeopleSoftServiceListeningConnector when I just put that address in a web browser I get what looks like SOAP xml with "IBRequest:getInfoXMLString(). ExternalOperationName is a required field." in faultstring tags.

Any insight into this problem would be great.  I don't know if I'm just doing it wrong or PS isn't configured properly and I'm really just fumbling in the dark.  Hell even if you just know where there is PS Component Interface documentation hidden somewhere that would be great.

EDIT:
After following Jon Skeet's advice to use fiddler I have this as the response from the webservice:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<IBInfo>
    <Status>
        <StatusCode>20</StatusCode>
        <MsgSet>158</MsgSet>
        <MsgID>10409</MsgID>
        <DefaultTitle>Integration Gateway Error</DefaultTitle>
    </Status>
</IBInfo>
```

Comment: That response body is as desired, but the error message suggests that the response header "Content-Type" on that response is correct.  In Fiddler, click the response "Headers" inspector and confirm that it's wrong.

You can use Fiddler's breakpoint debugging feature (see www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/video) to change the response content-type header and verify that it fixes the problem.

Comment: That's not a SOAP response. Was it meant to be SOAP?

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this when you've either used the wrong URL or done something else that's generated an error message instead of a normal XML response.

Try seeing what's in the response using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) - that should help.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Fiddler will definitely be useful here (and in the future).  I have updated question text with what fiddler has shown me.